# Unchecking checkbox in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

Created an report with checkbox using apex_item and when checked more than one check box i will display alert message "not to check more than one checkbox with ok button " after  clicking ok it should be unchecked . please find my JavaScript code that displays alert message

```
if($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 1)
{       
    var msg = alert('You are not allowed to select more than one employee');
}
```

Comment: On the surface, it sounds like you should be using a Radio Group item (which only allows one selection from a group) and not a Checkbox, no?

Comment: Ok thanks @Dan McGhan,I will change that to radio group .Help me out how to uncheck the check boxes after that alert message. Iam new and learning.Please help me researching for this more than one week

Comment: A radio group let the user only check 1 single element. So there is no need to alert the user.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use the APEX JavaScript APIs for this type of thing. You can find them here: https://apex.oracle.com/jsapi

If you're getting started with JavaScript and APEX, you may find these slides useful: https://www.slideshare.net/DanielMcGhan/getting-started-with-javascript-for-apex-developers

Here's a solution that should work for you (just change the name of the item to match yours):

```
var cbItem = apex.item('P1_CHECKBOX');

if (cbItem.getValue().length > 1) {       
  alert('You are not allowed to select more than one employee');

  cbItem.setValue(); // Passing nothing to clear the value
}
```

Comment: This is kind of like saying "this is how you sharpen your hammer" if someone is trying to chop down a tree with it...